# Разрядность системы

Tags: c++, память

Разбираясь в устройстве памяти, наткнулся на один момент касательно разрядности системы, насколько я понял в 32-разрядных системах под переменную, например, типа int отводится 32 бита, в результате выделяется 4 ячейки памяти под переменную (по 8 бит каждая), где частями хранится двоичный код значения переменной, переменная типа long int нуждается в 8ми байтах памяти, двоичный код такой переменной должен состоять из 64х бит, правильно ли я понимаю, что под разрядностью системы подразумевается кол-во бит отводящихся на переменную если так, то как long int помещается в 32- разрядных системах? И последний вопрос, почему 32-разрядная система не может использовать оперативную память больше 4х гигабайт ?

Comment: Вообще-то разрядность относится к размеру указателя. И как ни крути, 32  разрядами адрес более 4 Гб не получишь...

Comment: Я не специалист в этом вопросе, но могу предположить, что под long в 32 битной системе выделяется так же 64 бит, но только на 32х битных системах она считывается в 2 шага по 32 бита

Comment: В 32битной система шина адреса 32бита, с помощью 32бит можно адресовать только 2^32 элементов.

Comment: Про "не может" это не совсем верно https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090706-00/?p=17623

Comment: У вас вопрос про IBM совместимые или про любые? Или про физические возможности чипа, материнки?  Или про физические возможности планки памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под разрядностью системы обычно понимается разрядность памяти (разрядность адреса памяти) плюс также разрядность АЛУ (арифметическо-логическое устройство).

В 32-битной системе можно адресовать 32-битным адресом любой байт памяти, это означает что максимум может быть в системе 4ГигаБайт (т.е. 2^32 = 4Гига, около 10^9), в 64-разрядной можно адресовать 16 ЭкзаБайт (т.к. 2^64 = 16Экза, около 10^19). Адрес в С++ задаётся указателем, в 32-битной системе указатель будет 4-байтный, в 64-битной указатель 8-байтный.

По поводу АЛУ. 32-битное АЛУ означает что максимальный размер машинного слова АЛУ равен 32 битам, т.е. это максимальное целое число с которым возможны целочисленные операции такие как сложение, вычитание, умножение (результат умножения обычно доступен в два раза больший разрядности АЛУ) и деление (делимое обычно допускается в два раза большей разрядности чем АЛУ). У 64-битного АЛУ разрядность машинного слова 64 бита, т.е. процессор оперирует максимум 64 битными целыми числами.

Поясняю ваш вопрос про типы - размер типов не зависит от разрядности ни памяти ни АЛУ. Размер типов определяется только самим типом, а также операционной системой и компилятором. Обычно char - 8-битный, short - 16-битный, int - 32-битный, long long - 64-битный. Т.е. эти типы могут хранить указанное максимальное число бит внутри себя и в памяти они будут занимать ровно указанное число бит. А вот как компилятор в машинный код операции с этими типами скомпилирует, это уже зависит от размера АЛУ у процессора. Если АЛУ 32-битный то 64-битные типы (например long long) они будут эмулироваться с помощью 32-битных операци, т.е. будут занимать несколько инструкций, каждая 32-битная половинка слова будет отдельно складываться учитывая перенос между словами. Операции с типами меньшей чем АЛУ разрядности отлично исполняются в одну операцию, т.к. у 32-разрядной АЛУ родные операции 8, 16, 32 битные.

На самом деле в 32-битной системе можно получить доступ к более чем 4Гб памяти, но только с помощью специальных дополнительных обращений к системным вызовам оперционной системы ([Доступ к более чем 4Гб в 32-битной системе](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090706-00/?p=17623)). Стандартными С/С++ методами получить сплошной доступ сразу ко всей памяти больше 4Гб нельзя, т.к. в С/С++ указатели 32-битные для 32-битных систем. Чтобы получить доступ к расширенной памяти нужно будет использовать сочетание двух указателей - указатель на отдельный участок в 4Гб плюс указатель внутри этого участка, и этот доступ требует ОС вызовов.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то в 64 битной системе при создании переменной выделяется больший диапазон ячеек?

Comment: @John В 64-битной системе на все примитивные типы (числа, буквы) выделяется ровно столько же места сколько и в 32-битной, а именно выделяется ровно значащее количество байт, т.е. long long вот 64-битный тип, поэтому под неё как на 32 так и на 64-битной системах будет выделено ровно 64 бит, т.е. 8 байт. Зато кода для одной арифметической операции над 64-битными числами будет разное количество - на 32-системе будет несколько машинных инструкций, на 64-системе одна. Размер может только у сложных структур отличаться, т.к. в 64-системе выравниевание структуры будет на 8 байт, а в 32 на 4 байта.

Comment: Неверно. В программе любой битности можно использовать любой объем памяти. Просто это сложнее, если память не ложится на адресное пространство.

Comment: @VladD Напрямую в 32-битной С/С++ программе как есть использовать больше 4Гб нельзя, т.к. указатели 32 бита все. Чтобы иметь доступ к дополнительной памяти нужны более сложные механизмы, которые выходят за грань стандартного С++, какие то нативные обращения к ОС и т.п.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul: Да, обыкновенным 32-битным указателем нельзя адресовать больше 2^32 байт. Но вопрос-то о принципиальной возможности. А получать доступ не обязательно по указателю. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090706-00/?p=17623

Answer (score 1):

Размер переменных определяется реализацией (по стандарту), то есть под long могут отдавать как 64 бита, так и те же 32. Если в общем, то:

**sizeof(short)<=sizeof(int)<=sizeof(long)**

А 32 битная система просто не видит память более 4Гб, ведь у каждого байта памяти есть свой адрес. Переведём 4Гб в байты: 4*1024*1024*1024=2^32. Думаю, связь очевидна.